# How to get parent document immediately followed by child documents

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am working on hibernate search with the elastic search.I am having a requirement where I need to fetch parent document immediately followed by child documents.
To maintain parent and child relation I am having a table with id ,and parentId column.Here parentId is the id of another record.e.g

Note:For Better understanding run the belowsnippet

```html
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" >
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>ParentId</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Samule</td>
    <td>0</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>jhon</td>
    <td>1</td>
    
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>peeter</td>
    <td>2</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

expected output :

for ex: while searching name equals to **Samule** it needs to fetch in the below order

1

2

Here the first record is the parent record and the second record is the child record.Is there any way to do in elastic search with hibernate search?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see this possibly happen is if your hierarchy has a known maximum depth. For instance if you know you will only ever have two levels of parents, never three.

If this is your case, you can have a model like this:

```
@Indexed
public class Document {

  @DocumentId
  private int id;

  @Field
  private String text;

  @IndexedEmbedded(depth = /* YOUR MAX DEPTH HERE */)
  private Document parent;

  @Field(name = "path_sort", analyze = Analyze.NO)
  public String getPath() {
    return parent == null ? id : parent.getPath() + "." + id;
  }

}
```

And perform your search like this:

```
FullTextSession fts = ... ;

QueryBuilder qb = fts.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity( Document.class )
                .get();

Query query = qb.keyword().onFields(
                "text",
                "parent.text",
                "parent.parent.text"
                /* and so on, on as many levels as necessary */
        )
        .matching( "some string" )
        .createQuery();

Sort sort = qb.sort().byField( "path_sort" ).createSort();

List<Document> result = fts.createFullTextQuery( query, Document.class )
                .setSort( sort )
                .list();
```